# Using CMake targets in Visual Studio projects

Tags: c++, windows, cmake

I am pretty comfortable with CMake when used in Linux. That is, I use CMake to logically group my code into "targets" and abstract such things as "include directories" and other dependencies. Say, inside a large project my modus operandi would be to `add_library(..SHARED)` for a bunch of related files that provide one logically coherent unit, and `target_link_libraries(...)` to it from somewhere else.
(Of course, idiosyncrasies of CMake is another topic. I won't digress to discussions about e.g. its syntax.)
Now, for Windows 10. I fired up `Visual Studio 2019 Community` with the MSVC toolchain (that is, *not* WSL/WSL2), and created a `CMake Project` using `VS`'s "New Project" wizard.
It has created for me some boilerplate code, and the whole project tree looks as below:
[image]

In this image, `EnRouteGeneratedLibrary` is something I added as the next step. Inside it, I have one `*.hpp` file:

```
#pragma once

template<typename T>
class __declspec(dllexport) SampleTemplateKlass {
public:
    T sum(T x, T y) { return x + y; }
};

template class __declspec(dllexport) SampleTemplateKlass<int>;
```

and the `CMakeLists.txt`'s contents are as follows:

```
add_library(${TRG} SHARED ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/SampleTemplateKlass.hpp)

# set_target_sources(${TRG} PUBLIC SampleTemplateKlass.hpp)
set_target_properties(${TRG} PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)
target_include_directories(${TRG} PUBLIC .)
set(WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS 1)
```

Finally, in when building a simple "Hello World" executable, I have the following:

```
//

#include "SampleProjectWithDll.h"
#include "SampleTemplateKlass.hpp"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello CMake." << endl;
    SampleTemplateKlass<int> tmp;
    std::cout << tmp.sum(42, 314) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

(This is the boilerplate code created by VS + my additions).
I link as follows:

```
# CMakeList.txt : CMake project for SampleProjectWithDll, include source and define
# project specific logic here.
#
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

add_subdirectory(EnRouteGeneratedLibrary)

# Add source to this project's executable.
add_executable (SampleProjectWithDll "SampleProjectWithDll.cpp" "SampleProjectWithDll.h")
target_link_libraries(SampleProjectWithDll PUBLIC SampleLibrary)

# TODO: Add tests and install targets if needed.
```

When building all this, I get two errors,
`LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _DllMainCRTStartup` and `LNK1120 1 unresolved externals`with `SampleLibrary.dll` in the "File" field of the error panel.

The question is, how to make this simple "Hello World" compile and execute under Windows,
using the CMake infrastructure?

Comment: Looks like you are not exporting interface of your SHARED library with `__declspec(dllexport)`. There is also clear way to do that with `generate_export_header`

Comment: @jdfa Thanks for the headsup, I"ve updated my question. Problem persists.

Comment: Oh, I see. Didn't noticed that you have just one header in your library. Just add one .cpp file to that target which includes your header. Or consider other type of library